# Codeigniter shows views differently when index is removed

Tags: css, codeigniter, routes

I'm working in Codeigniter and Apache with a virtual host set up and have have added a .htaccess file to the rout directory (next to the index.php) with the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My view file is in another location outseide of the route and I have updated the index.php file to reflect this as below.

```
$system_path = '../CI/system';
$application_folder = '../CI/application';
$view_folder = '../CI/views';
```

If I access my website using the following addess it renders perfectly

```
localhost/tsh/public_html/index.php/home/index
```

However if I use any of the following it renders without applying any css etc.

```
localhost/tsh/public_html/home/index
localhost/tsh/public_html/home
localhost/tsh/public_html
```

Is anyone able to suggest why this is and how I can get around it? I've searched around but been unable to find any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `config/routs.php`

**Change this**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Path - `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

in your XAAMP Control Panel.

> Go to->Config->php.ini

Replace this

```
allow_url_include=on
```

in .htacess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

to avoid css  loading error.

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>folder/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Abdulla, I've made those changes but unfortunately it hasn't resolved the problem.

Comment: You are running this in server or localhost(XAMPP/WAMP)??

Comment: I'm running it on XAMPP

Comment: Hi, I've made that update (it was set to off) but again, no change.

Comment: your problem is loading css??

Comment: Yes, I believe so, the css loads fine when I use the full extension to view the page but when I use a shorter extension or remove the 'index.php' part the page displays with no css and or images

Comment: In my pc also having same problem. but i used this as solution.  <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>folder/path/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>

Comment: Aha! That's it, I built the web page separately and then imported it into CI and forgot to update the css links etc. Thank you so much for spending the time to work through it with me.

Comment: @Tessa Enjoy Coding. :)